# Restore previous variant of tag popup

Tags: feature-request, tags

Recently, the popup on hover on a tag was replaced by a larger, but less useful variant.

Especially as a mod, I often need to reference tag wikis to new users. With the "old version", the link to the tag's wiki was available directly from the popup. Now I need to open the list of tagged questions, wait for the page to load, just to be able to click the link to the tag wiki – which is, well, not efficient.

In return the popup now offers two buttons to subscribe or ignore a tag. Both actions one rarely uses – other than the links to a tag wiki, where one knows essential information (and references/links) have been accumulated.

So in short: I'd like to have the previous version back. At least optionally. Any hope?

PS: Now with the additional boxes, I feel the popups are really annoying:

[image: Tag Popup]

The "distracting part" now covers about 2/3 of the popup. I can't even remember when I last needed any of the 3 actions, let alone that frequent I'd like to have them there. IMHO those actions belong to the tag page itself, but not inside the tag popups. The only link I need from there is "view tag" – and for that I can simply click the tag itself. I'm really unhappy with the current state.

Comment: `[tag:tags]` → [tag:tags]

Comment: Still not "tag info page", but it contains the tag excerpt.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to write a user script that would allow you to do something like `[tag/wiki:tags]` to create a link to a tag wiki in the comments, especially if you start from [the comment link helper](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper).

Comment: So I should rather hope for SOUP implementing it? Please don't get me wrong, but to me that new popup seems to be a step backwards.

Comment: What is SOUP? .

Comment: @Dukeling [Stack Overflow Unoffical Patch](https://github.com/vyznev/soup) – and I've already [opened an issue with them](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues/42) to ask for this.

Comment: I was more thinking one could create a script for that oneself. If it's a somewhat minor change, or similar to something else, that tends to be the fastest and most reliable way to get it done. But that does require some coding.

Comment: And I cannot do that (the popup is loaded dynamically, it's not part of the original page source – and I have no idea at all how to deal with such stuff in UserScripts). If you write such a script, please let me know and I'd happily use it.

Comment: Do you happen to have a picture of the old version? I could have a go at making a userscript if you want :)

Comment: I wish I had made a screenshot then, @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ – but I didn't. The "bubbles" were much smaller, had the numbers of followers + questions using it as header, followed by the excerpt, followed by a line of links to tag-wiki ("info"), frequent etc. questions. Ah, image-search \o/ Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb1TC.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV0Fo.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I'll try having a look soon!

Comment: It's I who has to thank, @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ! Besides: note the second screenshot additionally has the "star" and "edit", so it seems to be from a looged-in user. The first misses the star, which could mean "not logged in" (so it makes no sense to star anything). I wouldn't mind if you ignore that, though – if login is required for the functionality I'd expect it to be asked for by the site itself after having clicked the link :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Done, But didn't you remove a comment too much – the one pointing to your UserScript?

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, I thought I'll repost it once it's fixed!

Answer (score 4):

I've added a feature to my userscript [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091) that adds a link to the wiki:

> [image: 'wiki' link added to tag popup]

To enable it, check the `Add a link to the tag wiki page on the popup that appears when hovering over a tag` feature under the `Appearance` section!

SOX has a bunch of other optional toggleable features you might like too :)

---

Note: the old tag popup did have a link to the top users too, but I think the wiki link is the most important, and most commonly used!

Comment: Full ack (top users) – and thanks a lot! I had preferred a built-in solution by SE over installing "yet another UserScript" – but in a way I'm glad you've been faster. I start valuing several other features of your script, makes a mods life easier indeed :) +1 for now (on the topic), though the "accept" tick might move to a "native solution" if any comes. That's not rating your script, but the connection to the topic then :)

Comment: No problem! I agree userscripts will never be as good as it being native but hopefully SOX will make it worthwhile :P

Comment: Also feel free to unaccept it, I have a feeling 'accepted' feature requests might not be looked at by the team!

Comment: Good point. And it won't hurt your rep as this is meta ;)