# Tag popup for `[tag:]` markdown no longer working in posts

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, popups

When hovering over a tag 'under' a question, a [popup with extended information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/295232) is shown. While the [usefulness is under discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313909/295232), and people like me write [userscripts](https://stackapps.com/q/8054/34061) to fill the gaps, I noticed it's not being applied consistently throughout the system.

In posts, you can use Markdown commands `[tag:]` and `[meta-tag:]` to show nicely formatted tag links like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). They look exactly like the tags under the question, yet when you hover over them you only get a meager link description (left):

[image] |
[image]

This leads to [situations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/deleted-questions/info) where the tag in the top of the page has a hover popup (right), but the same tag a few lines below doesn't.

Curiously, while writing this post, I noticed that the preview does have a hover for the tag (left):

[image] |
[image]

Another place to add the popup would be the 'Related Tags' widget in the right sidebar of the tag info pages (right).

Comment: On MSE there's no need for the "meta-" prefix. Without it, the tag popup works fine, so this request is moot, at least here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it still doesn't work [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319546/295232), even with `[tag:discussion]` instead of `[meta-tag:discussion]`...

Comment: Huh. It works in preview and I am 100% sure it used to work until today. So this is a new bug.

Comment: OK, never realized that, but if you're sure it's a [bug], I'm fine.

Comment: Sure as I can be, but there's always a chance I'm still wrong. Let's hope they fix it, whether a bug or not.

Comment: Glorfindel I just make a post that was closed  as "duplicate" of this, no problem with that. What about if you add [tag:status-review] to this post? P.S. There is an older post about the same from 2011 that has already answered --- status-by-design, the link is in my post.